# Mapping objects of old to new in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this function but it is having only one object in each variable but there are an array of 3 objects in input.

```
ctrl.func = function (oldDetails, newDetails) {
            var oldDetailsCollection =[];
            var newDetailsCollection = [];
            _.forEach(oldDetails, function (oldDetails) {
                oldDetailsCollection = _.find(oldDetails.doctorDetails);
            });
            _.forEach(newDetails, function (newDetails) {
                newDetailsCollection = _.find(newDetails.doctorDetails);
            });
    }
```

Now, the oldDetailsCollection and newDetailsCollection has exactly same properties as below:

```
iD
doctorName
```

Also, input contains array of 3 objects of above properties, but I get only one time the property values. What am I missing or how to correct this to store array of 3?

Example:

I have this:

```
iD = 1 doctorName = "Alice"

iD= 2 doctorName = "Brown"

iD = 3 doctorName = "Stu"
```

However, I get only the first values

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your question. Can you show your current array output and expected array output?

Comment: @Ephraim: Thank you so much, the current array output at this point in my code "oldDetails.doctorDetails" is array of 3 objects with ID and DoctorName as mentioned above. I expect to map the same to the newObject variable I created and then map this back to the parent inputobject oldDetails

Comment: What is your main objective? Do you want to copy the array oldDetails into oldDetailsCollection and etc.? By copy I mean all the elements.

Comment: @Ephraim: The elements are just iD and doctorName I gave the values also above in example